# how to iterate thru json array and pull values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have the following JSON that is being displayed on an order confirmation page:

```
var orderDetails = {
    "orderID": "o32770183",
    "orderQty": 3,
    "orderTotal": 575.97,
    "orderShipping": 49.97,
    "orderDiscount": 0,
    "orderTax": 39.74,
    "orderCity": "Norwalk",
    "orderState": "Connecticut",
    "itemId": [
        "sku500134",
        "sku230312",
        "sku133846"
    ],
    "itemQty": [
        1,
        1,
        1
    ],
    "itemPrice": [
        159.99,
        225.99,
        189.99
    ],
    "itemName": [
        "The 'Inaugural' Raymond R Cabernet Sauvignon",
        "H de l'Hospitalet",
        "Chateau Florie Aude"
    ]
}
```

What would be the best approach to pulling the data out?

Comment: *"So I have the following JSON..."* That's not JSON. It's a JavaScript [object initializer](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) (aka "object literal"). [JSON](http://json.org) is a subset thereof, but when you have such a thing in your JavaScript code, it's not JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - cool seeing you around here again :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Is there such a thing as a standard "wrapper"? JSON could really use one, if only for the purpose of changing the name.

Comment: @amnotiam: Huh? Not following you. Why would you want a wrapper around an object initializer?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: No, not around an object, around the JSON standard so we can call it something else that doesn't start with "JS". I know, it was a stretch. `;)`

Comment: @amnotiam: :-) Gotcha. No, not aware of another term...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - You have confused me, I figured it was all JSON.

Comment: @jrutter: That's the trouble. It confuses a lot of people. JSON is a text based data interchange format used to transfer data to and from different language environments. The JS in JSON has nothing to do with anything except that the style of the data structures were patterned after JavaScript's object/array literal notations. Aside from that, it isn't part of any language. Sort of like XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually not JSON, that's a plain old JavaScript object.  You pull the data our just like with any other object

```
var orderId = orderDetails.orderID;
```

or

```
var orderId = orderDetails["orderID"];
```

or for arrays:

```
var itemQtyArr = orderDetails.itemQty;
for(var i = 0, max = itemQtyArr.length; i < max; i++){
   console.log("itemQty", i, itemQtyArr[i]);
}
```

or the dynamic approach Vivek posted (+1 to him)

Comment: Or as this is tagged `jquery`, there's always `$.each(orderDetails.itemQty, function(index, entry) { ... });`

Comment: Tj which is slower, i'd rather use `for in`

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: Not in the real world, unless you're dealing with millions of entries: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I accept either are equally fast (never doubted it) - but is there an advantage to using $.each over a simple for loop?  Is it just personal preference?

Comment: @AdamRackis: I'd call it personal preference. With the function, you gain variable scoping and such. But totally style, I'd say. I used to do `for` loops. Once I tested the runtime cost, I mostly switched over to `forEach` and `$.each` for the scoping.

Comment: TJ i agree with your point, but in this case there's no need for context as he's not iterating over jquery objects, just key value pairs. I think `for in` suffices, that's what jquery does in the background anyways but passes in the context to the callback.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: I'm not talking about [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each), I'm talking about [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each). (Yes, it's ***very*** unfortunate that they used the same name for, um, each of them.)

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: As for `itemQty`, it's about the `for(var i = 0` loop above, for which `for in` is not a replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Or also, like this - a more dynamic approach - (if you dont know the objects elements)

```
for(i in orderDetails)
  alert(orderDetails[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the keys of a Javascript Object using for in

Lets say

```
a = {"a":"hello","b":"world"};

for(var c in a){
  console.log(c); //will out put a,b in iterations
  console.log(a[c]) //will access values of keys a and b from the object a output hello, world
}
```

Comment: There is no "JSON object" in your code. See comment on the question for details.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - what would be an example of a JSON object?

Comment: @jrutter: See the comment on the question for the distinction between a JavaScript object initializer (which is what Abid is using) and JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful JSON Editor tool that gives you a visual representation of your JSON object. It lists your named items and gives you the path to access your JSON values: [JSON Editor](http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/)